# Regex replacement in C++11

Tags: regex, c++11

I need to replace a string of the type `T1.9` with the string `unit19`. The number of digits could vary e.g.`T34.999` should become `unit34999`. Here is my progress:

```
std::regex e ("^(T\d+\.\d+)$");
std::string result (std::regex_replace(version, e, "") );
```

What should I write for format? Or is the approach to replace the string in one, no two, iterations, wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust the capturing groups in the pattern and use backreferences in the replacement pattern:

```
^T([0-9]+)[.]([0-9]+)$
```

and replace with `unit$1$2`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hN9xA7/1)

A [test at IDEONE](https://ideone.com/sO2vUg):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    strings.push_back("T34.999");
    strings.push_back("T1.9");
    std::regex reg("^T([0-9]+)[.]([0-9]+)$");
    for (size_t k = 0; k < strings.size(); k++)
    {
        std::cout << std::regex_replace(strings[k], reg, "unit$1$2") << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I always struggle with regular expressions. This time I managed to customize your example for my other regex tasks of today.